# Office 365 MX record for subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, mx-record, microsoft-office-365

I have a domain registered with an external registrar (marcaria.com). It is configured to be handled by Office365. (DNS name servers set to ns1 (and ns2) .bdm.microsoftonline.com). I have a contracted newsletter agency, who wants to use a subdomain to send out newsletters.

They asked me to create a subdomain and delegate the NS record to them. Turns out this can't be done in Office 365 - I couldn't create subdomains with NS records. (Did I miss something?)

Since NS failed, they gave me a list of A, TXT and MX records to create. I could create the A and TXT records, but I don't see MX as an option.

In `Admin`/`Domains`/`mydomain.com`, in the `DNS Settings`, I have a `New custom record` button, but that only allows the creation of TXT, A, CNAME and AAAA records. No MX. There is a section that says `Exchange Online` records, and one of my created TXT records was automatically put there, but I can't add records to that section. (Also, now I can't delete that TXT record which was automatically moved here, which is a worry. There is an edit button next to it, but no delete. Can change it, can't remove it. Sweet.)

So, any ideas? Is this even possible in Office 365 (delegating a subdomain, like newsletter.mydomain.com)?

Thank you!

Comment: Looking at [Microsoft's own documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-edit-custom-DNS-records-in-Office-365-af00a516-dd39-4eda-af3e-1eaf686c8dc9), I don't see `NS` or `MX` as types you can select. I'll defer this to an Office 365 expert, but I think you might not be able to accomplish this while letting Office 365 manage DNS for your domain.

Comment: Further confirmation at the bottom of that page: ***Need to update your MX record?** First, make sure that you manage the DNS for your domain, not Office 365.*

Comment: Well, darn. Thanks for the answer. I was suspecting this, but wasn't sure I understood the documentation correctly. I was gonna have to move DNS management to Azure anyway, but with marcaria every change is a PITA... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I'm leaving this question unanswered in case an Office 365 expert can offer you some better advice. I'm just a DNS guy, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since NS failed, they gave me a list of A, TXT and MX records to create. I could create the A and TXT records, but I don't see MX as an option.

If you select Office 365 as your DNS provider you CANNOT host email or IM with another hosting company.https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Can-I-add-custom-subdomains-or-multiple-domains-to-Office-365-5481401f-7771-490e-b728-b3a81305a32e

> They asked me to create a subdomain and delegate the NS record to them. Turns out this can't be done in Office 365 - I couldn't create subdomains with NS records. (Did I miss something?)

If you want to add a subdomain or your domain you MUST change your DNS management to a DNS provider other than Office 365.https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Can-I-add-custom-subdomains-or-multiple-domains-to-Office-365-5481401f-7771-490e-b728-b3a81305a32e

Comment: Yep, thanks, this is what I figured out too. Unfortunately, these things cannot be done if O365 is my DNS provider. I ended up migrating everything to Azure, where I could add all the DNS records I needed. Thanks.